# purpose or result : so (that)

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning, conjunctions

from Longman Contemporary:

> so (that)
>
> a) in order to make something happen, make something possible etc   He
> lowered his voice so Doris couldn’t hear.
>
> Why don’t you start out early so that you don’t have to hurry?
>
> b) used to say that something happens or is true as a result of the
> situation you have just stated
>
> There are no buses, so you’ll have to walk.
>
> The gravestones were covered with moss, so that it was impossible to
> read the names on them.

Q: a) He lowered his voice so Doris couldn’t hear.

I think 'so Doris couldn't hear' sounds more like a result than a purpose.

Am I correct? Is there any way to properly distinquish between them when you use 'so that'?

If you are a native English speaker,

1. When you **read**, what's the first feelling of it? result or purpose
2. When you **hear**, what's the first feelling of it? result or purpose

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The obvious interpretation of *He lowered his voice so Doris couldn't hear* is that the speaker wanted to keep his words a secret from Doris - that was his *purpose*.

However, if the context was that Doris was eavesdropping without the speaker's knowledge, it *could* mean that he lowered his voice for some other reason, with the *result* that she couldn't hear any more.

Comment: To Kate, Do you think it's a result or purpose?

Comment: I thought that was clear from my answer, but as it evidently wasn't I have edited the answer.

Comment: Agreed, and there's no difference between hearing it and reading it.

Comment: By the way, if OP is concerned about being misunderstood, they could reword it so it’s clear (and did you notice what I did just there? :-).   For instance, “He lowered his voice to prevent Doris’s hearing,” or, “He lowered his voice, and thus Doris couldn’t hear.”